# RGBDSLAM indigo

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Thanks to Felix Endres for his great package.

I use RGBDSLAM on ROS indigo (Ubuntu 14.04) with freenect driver.

I see errors messages : "Using Standard kinect /openni_camera -> /openni_rgb_optical_frame as transformation (This message is throttled to 1 per 5 seconds)".

May be a problem with freenect (instead of openni ?).

Thanks for reply

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223810/rgbdslam-indigo/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I remember correctly, this just means that rgbdslam doesn't receive the tf  transformation from `/openni_camera` to `/openni_rgb_optical_frame`. Maybe the frames are called differently with freenect. However this shouldn't impede functionality unless you intentionally modified and the mentioned transformation and want to use it (e.g. for extrinsically calibrating the camera to a robot).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0